# Need a client caching strategy with OfflineFirst for mobile client w shared objects

Tags: caching, mobile, ionic2, local-storage, offline-caching

Does anyone know a clever or standard solution for a client caching policy in an OfflineFirst design.

I have an Ionic2 (Angular2/TypeScript) client and am trying to follow OfflineFirst principles, so assuming there's an unpredictable connection. I want to only download objects, which are shared across multiple users, in an many-to-many relation, that have changed since the last client update and update the local storage of the client only with changes since last update.

Here's my current impression:
- Any push strategy doesnt make sense it seems, given the offline first? So some suggestions have been to use Observable/Observer pattern, but this uses Push strategy, which I don't think is a good solution therefor. 
- I ve thought about storing a user-lastupdate key-value pair on the server together with a lastupdate ts for each object, and then compare the 2 each time the client comes online and pings for new updates. if there are updates, then download those objects with a ts newer than last user update ts. 
- i ve also seen some mentions of service workers, but am not familiar with it.
- others chose costly solutions as simply doing a full refresh on periodic pings, ie every day, every 4 hours or so.

Any insights would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern that I've seen used in Offline First apps that use CouchDB (or related technologies such as Cloudant) is to do what's called one-database-per-user. The basic idea is to assign a CouchDB database to every user when they register for the app. Then, only allow each individual user to read/write that user's CouchDB database. Tools like Hoodie or Cloudant Envoy (Envoy provides the "illusion" of one-database-per-user to the client) can help with this:

- http://hood.ie/
- https://github.com/cloudant-labs/envoy

This approach works well for apps with well-segmented user data (e.g. a personal TODO list), and scales out surprisingly well. The approach presents challenges, though, when you want to share data between users (e.g. a shared TODO list), or you want to run analytics on aggregate data across users.

It appears that your app would fall into this "shared data between user" category. The challenge is, how to get the shared data from User Database A into User Database B? In CouchDB speak, this shared data would be represented as a JSON document.

One architecture is to use a message queue with a publisher and subscriber agent assigned to each every user database. These agents would run on the server side, within your security policies for who has what access to what data. These agents would subscribe to "channels" of data within other user databases, and on the flip side publish to "channels" of data. These channels could be defined by specific attributes contained within documents in the database. When an agent detects an event that is described to, it runs a filtered replication to copy the data in question from one user database to another.